# Is there a way to render large querysets in Django templates as the query is populated?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a queryset that is rather large and a server thats really slow. When im rendering my template, I noticed that the page only renders after the queryset has been populated. In order to increase the speed of the page loading, I am thinking that maybe my page can render the queryset on the fly as the queryset is being filtered but im not sure if there is an implementation like this in Django.  My queryset has well over 1000 items that have roughly 20 attributes each and i need to show all of them on the page. I tried playing around with my Handsontable render but I discovered that the time taken is to actually run the queryset filter and not so much the handsontable render.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction , it will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you don't use any special method like AJAX calls or websockets, the whole response will be send to the client at once. While you could also stream a response incrementally it does not work well with HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow @commish :)

To clear out some basics, when you say "on the fly" you're probably thinking of something like youtube where video is getting streamed to you constantly.

This is not how Django processes requests and response.

What actually is happening is something like this:

1. Webpage hits the url (example: localhost:8000/list/)
2. Request is recived by django view function
3. It calls the database and waits until all the objects have been received
4. Django uses the queryset to build an html response
5. Django sends back this response

(it's not exactly like this, but simplified for explanation).

If you want to reduce the time taken by steps 3 & 4 as your queryset is large your easiest options would be to "paginate" your request.

So for example instead of sending all 1000 items back, send only 100 items back for the 1st page. Then when the user clicks on "Load more" or goes to a url like (localhost:8000/list/?page=2) you load the next set of 100 items and so on.

Django has documentation for this which explains this concept in a detailed fashion: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/